# Call ssrs report

Tags: .net

I am getting below issue to call ssrs report. Could you please look into this?

The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
 Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message: --      Error - Report Manager             This page might not function correctly because either your browser does not support scripts or active scripting is disabled.         [Home](/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx) | [My Subscriptions](/Reports/Pages/Subscriptions.aspx) | Help      SQL Server Reporting Services

Error                                    The item '/Corporate/BusinessExcellence/OptumOps/HSC/HSC_Summary_Report/ReportExecution2005.asmx' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound) Get Online Help            [Home](/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx)          --.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

1) rdls should be opened with IE not any other browser (like chrome, firefox etc)
2) make sure you can access the base report server .
3) Can you build and view your rdl in bids? Make sure to delete .data file from bin folder before you re-render if any changes made.